# How do I read the correct Stream/byte[] from HttpPostedFile InputStream property?

Tags: c#, http, memory, io, stream

I get a `HttpPostedFile` that is being uploaded (supposedly a pdf), and I have to use it's `stream` to initialize it in PdfSharp.

The problem is that, altough `HttpPostedFile` `SaveAs()` method saves a valid pdf, saving it's `InputStream` doesn't create a valid pdf, so when I use the `InputStream` on PdfSharp to read the pdf it throws an exception with "Invalid Pdf", and saving the `InputStream` byte[]
which I tried to get like this:

```
    public byte[] GetBytesFromStream(System.IO.Stream uploadedFile)
    {
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(uploadedFile.Length); //Length: 103050706
        string str = "";

        byte[] input = new byte[length];

        // Initialize the stream.
        System.IO.Stream MyStream = uploadedFile;

        // Read the file into the byte array.
        MyStream.Read(input, 0, length);
        
        return input;
    }
```

Calling the method like this:

```
byte[] fileBytes = GetBytesFromStream(uploadedFile.InputStream);
```

But creating a file from those bytes creates an invalid pdf too...

I created the file from bytes like this...

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.pdf", fileBytes);
```

I have 2 questions about this then:

1st - Why is the stream I receive from the InputStream invalid, and the SaveAs Works.

2nd - How could I get the correct stream from the inputStream or the HttpPostedFile, without saving the file to disk and then reading it.

Comment: Check InputStream Position, it's probably not 0, so set it to 0 before reading into byte array.

Comment: I don't know what to say but, thank you! How didn't I think of that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed that this question wasn't answered (since Evk's comment was the solution) and I couldn't accept any answer.

So I'm making this one just to not leave this question unanswered.

tl;dr;
The solution as per Evk's comment was the position of the stream, it was being read beforehand and setting the position to 0 before trying to create the pdf was enough to fix the problem.